# ASP.NET MVC : validation domain password

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, security, jquery-ui

In an ASP.NET MVC 3.0 application (intranet), the end user is logged on the domain (sample : `MyDomain\User1`. In my application there is a validation section, when I want to valid a jQuery UI popup appear and I have to enter password of the user logged.

I'd like to know :

- how can I check if the password receive in the action method match with the `User1` domain password
- Is there a way to secure the password. To be clear, I have input (password type), in the model received from the form the password is in clear. Is it normal? Is there way to crypt that. I used ajax for posting.

**Update1**
After internal discuss here .. is it possible to do an Asynchrone Ajax post with the password and make a check (password match to password of the user in the domain, the user is authenticated over NTLM protocol) without use LDAP.
Thanks,

Comment: To secure your password/login use SSL! For an intranet application you can use a self signed certificate.

Comment: Sorry no SSL :(. Could you tell me more about "self signed certificate" ? The goal is check if the password receive from the form match with the user domain password

Comment: Self signed certificate http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-signed_certificate

Comment: How to generate it in IIS7 http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753127(v=ws.10).aspx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not just use [Windows Authentication](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2006/07/12/Recipe_3A00_-Enabling-Windows-Authentication-within-an-Intranet-ASP.NET-Web-application.aspx)

Otherwise: Consult [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180890%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

Gives a complete walkthrough of custom authentication against an Active Directory controller.

Comment: The goal is check if the password enter in the input match with the domain password. There is "something" to do to do this check in the action method

Comment: Yes ... but I have bad experience with LDAP (make me crazy). If no other solution, I'll use it but I hope not ;-) I expected may be something out of the box with MVC.